# Read all the tables from Oracle database using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqoop

**Objective:** To read all the tables from a oracle database in Spark.

**Findings:** I have written code to read a single table.I can reuse this multiple times to read multiple tables but this will connect to my oracle database number of tables I will read.

```
val employees = sqlContext.load(
    "jdbc",
    Map("url" -> "url")",
    "dbtable" -> "tableName")
)
```

As per the spark documentation in "dbtable" parameter we can only have the table name or any subquery.
Do we have any option like sqoop import-all-tables in spark to read the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same scenario, where I need to take the backup of Cassandra tables. We came with a solution, where we have listed out all the table names within a Keyspace as a text file. We have written a Shell script from which I read the file and pass the keyspace and table name as a parameters to the Spark code.

Note- This is not a good way. Sqoop is meant for these kind of scenarios.